# C# Linq in extension / method

Tags: c#, linq, methods

Greetings

I'm looking for creating a extension method including a linq query.
What i'm looking for is either a method or extension method which can do something like this

```
var orderedList = OrderThisList<ModelName>(List<T> sourceList, //and something like m=>m.Username);
```

Where ModelName is the entity and Username is the field of which I want to order.
The method would look something like

```
public List<T> OrderThisList<T>(//some linq property?)
{
    //What code goes here?
}
```

Comment: Where is the data meant to come from?

Comment: If you're already passing in a `List<T>`, why don't you just use `OrderBy` directly? Or are you trying to sort the list in-place? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: It's still extremely unclear what this question is all about, but it sounds like we're dealing with in-memory collections rather than LINQ to SQL etc.

*If* the problem with using `OrderBy` is that it doesn't sort the list in-place, you should be using `List<T>.Sort()`, possibly passing in a custom comparator.

My [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) project has a few helper types which may help you. For example:

```
var comparison = ProjectionComparer<ModelType>.Create(m => m.SomeProperty)
                                              .ThenBy(m => m.SomeOtherProperty);
list.Sort(comparison);
```

---

If you're using LINQ to SQL and you've got a [data context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx), you could use:

```
public List<TSource, TKey> OrderThisList<TSource, TKey>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> ordering)
{
    return dataContext.GetTable<TSource>()
                      .OrderBy(ordering)
                      .ToList();
}
```

Now obviously that requires *two* type arguments, and you only want to specify one. There are various ways round this - basically you'd want to end up with a generic type and a method with *one* type argument (`TKey`) which can be inferred. For example:

```
var list = Orderer<ModelType>.Create(dataContext)
                             .OrderThisList(m => m.SomeProperty);
```

It's somewhat round-the-houses though considering that `OrderBy` is already available... could you explain why you want this, and also what LINQ provider is involved?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to convert 50 lines of ordering code into something smaller.

Comment: @Levisaxos: Without really knowing what those 50 lines of ordering code do, it's hard to help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Thank you but I can't give all detail due to copywrite. This helps me for now!

Comment: @Levisaxos: I'm not asking you to post copyright code. I'm asking you to explain what you're trying to achieve more clearly... in particular, what you want to do that the built-in OrderBy method doesn't do. Are you trying to sort in-place (which OrderBy doesn't do)? Do you *need* to sort in-place?

Comment: Because for each type of ordering there is about 3/4 more lines of code to be handled. But this is the same for every entity. With the above code (slightly changed) I can make a method which orders the list and returns it and handles the other code.

Comment: @Levisaxos: I think you'll find my edited answer more helpful, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built in Linq method `var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Username)`  You shouldn't need to write your own extension method to sort a list.

Comment: I should, but I wont, so this doesn't answer my question!

Comment: @Levisaxos: But *why* won't you? If an answer doesn't help you, you should explain why, so that other answers can be given which will be more helpful. Currently this is like playing "Guess which number I'm thinking of."